# I need to post links into an excel table with vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, paste

To try to English my issue, I am trying to duplicate data from one page to a second page where the destination is a table for sorting and filtering benefits. I want to use links or formulas (=Worksheets("Data Banking").Range("B14") in Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Range("B14") but this page may hold upto 10,000 rows at 16 columns wide before the data is archived. I don't mind a short delay, upto a couple of minutes, but I am stumped. Here is a sample of my code so far:

```
Sub test()
    LRBL = Sheets("DATA Banking").Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Worksheets("Data Banking").Range("B14:Q" & LRBL + 10).Copy
    Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Range("B10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True ***this line throws the error
    Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Columns("B:Q").AutoFit
    
End Sub
```

I think this does not work because the destination I am trying to post to is in a table.

I am not new to programming but have never worked with tables before and the above code has become rather adhoc while I try to figure out what I am missing.

If I change the destination to a cell on "Banking Ledger" that is not "in the table", the above, and several less verbose versions, worked well but if I try to paste to a cell or range in the table itself, it throws me a run-time 1004 App defined or obj defined error. I am guessing there is more to tables that I know so any help, no matter how "for dummies" it might be would be awesome.

I have also had issues with this whole tables thing in that to add 70 rows to insert new data into requires a for loop and inserting a single row in each loop.

I like the filtering and sorting that the tables can do but This page is a "view only" page and gets its data from another editable page by someone with higher security access, thus the desire to use the links to the editable page.

table has the label table13 if that helps in a solution.

Comment: So you are trying to copy from a table to a range in a different sheet? or copy from a table into another table in a different sheet?

Comment: Wrong both times. Origin data is in a standard range of cells but the destination is a table. I don't need the filtering on the "edit" version of the data "DATA Banking" only on the viewing version of the data "Banking Ledger". Hope you can understand my gibberish

Comment: Or to say it a different way, "DATA Banking" is standard cells and is used for editing data while "Banking Ledger" contains "table 13" which grows as the origin range grows but needs to contain links to keep the viewed data current

Comment: Can you provide sample of your **DATA Banking** and **Banking Ledger** sheets? even if it's dummy data

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your interest and desire to help. I found the solution, and while I was able to edit it successfully and make it work, I cant say I fully understand it. Col2Ltr is a UDF that converst a column number to its corresponding letter

```
For jj = 2 To 17
    Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Activate
    Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Range(Col2ltr(jj) & "14").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='DATA Banking'!RC"
    CCN = Cells(ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value
    Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Range("Table13[" & CCN & "]").FormulaR1C1 = "='DATA Banking'!RC"
Next jj

Worksheets("Banking Ledger").Columns("B:Q").AutoFit
```

It appears a table can access a cell on another sheet by simply referencing it's "RC" (RowColumn I am guessing). I am glad I didn't have to offset that data to a different range from the origin. Would not have known where to start on that, but that was not, and is not, my issue today.